# Interstitial Ads by PubCenter Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, ads

Currently I am using GoogleAdmob but it doesn't providing SDK For windows phone 8.1 that's why I am moving to PubCenter.

I have monetized my app on pubcenter there is option for size where we can choose any size for our app. I want to integrate Interstitial Ads in my app by pubcenter but I don't know how to implement.

Comment: Sorry, this is rather too broad for Stack Overflow. It is much better for you to show what technical solution you have at present, and _specifically_ where you are stuck. If the answer is "I am stuck on all of it" then you may be best looking at the documentation for PubCenter, as a full solution is probably out of the scope of questions here. Have a look at the Help Centre when you get a moment.

Comment: I have tried to search on google and even on pubcenter but have not find any solution that why this question is here . If you know then please tell me solution.